# Detecting Mouse Click on an Array of Controls

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I'm adding an array of Panel objects (which in turn contain other items) to a form at runtime. Then, I'm assigning a click event to each panel inside a loop like so:

```
pnlInstrument[index].Click += pnlInstrument_Click;
```

The empty click function looks like this:

```
private void pnlInstrument_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

The event is triggering correctly, but how can I tell which panel was clicked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `sender` parameter of the event method..

```
private void pnlInstrument_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel panel = (sender as Panel); //This is the panel.
}
```

**Edit:**  For comments of getting index..

```
private void pnlInstrument_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel panel = (sender as Panel); //This is the panel.
    int panelIndex = Array.IndexOf(pnlInstrument, panel);
}
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch, sir.  +1 ;)

Comment: Halfway there! Can I get the object's index in the array from that?

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
pnlInstrument[index].Click += pnlInstrument_Click;
pnlInstrument[index].Tag += index;

private void pnlInstrument_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel pnl = (Panel)sender;
    int index = (int)pnl.Tag;
}
```